# Give value instead of column on foreign key in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `TABLE_ACCOUNT` and `TABLE_ACTYPE`.

The `TABLE_ACCOUNT` has columns

```
 (CODE, NAME, TRADE, CATGORY, ACTYPE)
```

and the `TABLE_ACTYPE` has columns

```
(CODE, NAME, ITYPE)
```

The data in the `TABLE_ACTYPE` is:

```
CODE     NAME     ITYPE
-----------------------
1        TRADE1    1
1        CAT1      2
1        ACT1      3
```

Primary key for this table is `CODE, TYPE`

The data in the `TABLE_ACCOUNT` is :

```
CODE, NAME, TRADE, CATEGORY, ACTYPE
-----------------------------------
1     Name1  1       1          1
```

I want to create the 3 foreign keys for to `table_account`

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_ACCOUNT WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE_ACCOUNT_TABLE_ACTYPE_TRADE 
FOREIGN KEY ([TRADE,1]) REFERENCES [TABLE_ACTYPE] (CODE, ITYPE)

ALTER TABLE TABLE_ACCOUNT WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE_ACCOUNT_TABLE_ACTYPE_CAT 
FOREIGN KEY ([TRADE,2]) REFERENCES [TABLE_ACTYPE] (CODE, ITYPE)

ALTER TABLE TABLE_ACCOUNT WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE_ACCOUNT_TABLE_ACTYPE_ACTYPE 
FOREIGN KEY ([TRADE,3]) REFERENCES [TABLE_ACTYPE] (CODE, ITYPE)
```

Is this possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Comment: Look into supertype/subtype and make a supertype table to which you can FK just once.

Comment: I HAVE ADDED COLUMNS TO TABLE_ACCOUNT NAME (CODETRADE WITH DEFAULT VALUE 1), (CODECAT WITH DEFAULT VALUE 2), (CODEITYPE WITH DEFAULT VALUE 3) THEN MAKE FOREIGN KEYS :)